# Spring securiy configuration based on URL?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, security, spring-security

I have two web applications `WebApp1` and `WebApp2`.WebApp1 has its own spring security configuration and WebApp2 has its own spring security configuration. Now i am providing a link in `WebApp1` to access `WebApp2`. On click of link in WebApp1, i would receive a url to invoke a page in `WebApp2` as `http://somehost:8080/some.jsp?param1=value1&param2=value2`

Now the problem is `WebApp1` users and `WebApp2` users are different and they reside in different LDAP directory. Now when user1 sends a request from WebApp1 to WebApp2 i just need to check whether the `user1` is a valid user or not.

My question is whenever a URL comes as below:

```
http://somehost:8080/some.jsp?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

Then i need to validate against the different LDAP security configuration. Because WebApp2 already has LDAP security and `user1` will be in different LDAP. 
Basically i need two different security configurations based on URL mentioned above. whenever a url comes as above mentioned then i `spring default login form should popup and ask for credentials then it has to validate against different ldap security configuration` and after validating send the user to `http://somehost:8080/some.jsp?param1=value1&param2=value2`
Is it possible?  or is there any way to communicate these two webapps in a secured way. i mean only valid users should invoke `http://somehost:8080/some.jsp?param1=value1&param2=value2` ?

Thanks!

Comment: OAuth can be used here, for sharing services between different applications.